# Having trouble locating files that are filling up disk space

Tags: 12.04, server, partitioning, mediaserver, mediatomb

I'm still getting used to Linux and I finally had my media server up and running but now my boot partition is full and mediatomb is longer sharing files (I think the issues are related since they happened about the same time).  I am running Ubuntu 12.04 Server and when I logged in the other day my partition usage was up to 99% of a 25 GB partition.  I can't figure out what files are taking up all the space and I've been searching the internet for a couple days now trying to find a way to identify what is doing this.  I have separate partitions for system files and other files that are shared on the network (sda1 for the boot files and sda2 for my shared files which also shows up as sda5 as it is set up as a logical volume).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the output of `df -ih` command?

Answer (score 1):

You can use find command to list 40 Largest files in a file system/directory

```
find /path -xdev -type f -size +10000c -ls | sort -nrk 7,7 | head -40
```

Du is also use full to verify and find large folders

```
du -x -sh /path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these commands.

- Go to the directory with help of `cd` command, where you want to search.
- And then execute this command.

```
 find . -exec du -hd 1 {} \; | sort -hr >>output2.txt
```

- It will list size of all the files/directory to the file named **`output2.txt`**, in the current working directory. You can look at the **output** and find out where the problem is.
- It'll take little time, but you'll get the Info.

Hope it helps ...:)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try `sudo apt-get clean` (it clears the local cache of downloaded packages). Depending on how many updates you installed, that can be quite a few GB.

You probably don't have 25GB of packages, but that's essentially free...