# Problem IN piping the output of one command to other

Tags: scripts, sort, pipe

I want to recursively sort  all the file in the present directly.

I tried `ls -lh -R |sort >> output.txt`. But i think multi-threading problem is creating a problem, before complete output of `ls -lh -R`, the sort has started to do it's work.

 Now i'm getting wrong answer. How can I do it properly .
I was trying to : [ANSWER THIS QUESTION](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344924/having-trouble-locating-files-that-are-filling-up-disk-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to do with multi-threading. After `ls` completed its task, its all output will be send to `sort`, never before.

An explanation more elevated:

> A Unix pipe connects the STDOUT (standard output) file descriptor of
>   the first process to the STDIN (standard input) of the second. What
>   happens then is that **when the first process writes to its STDOUT,
>   that output can be immediately read (from STDIN) by the second
>   process**.
>
> Using multiple pipes is no different than using a single pipe. Each
>   pipe is independent, and simply links the STDOUT and STDIN of the
>   adjacent processes.
>
> [...] pipes, as such, are consistent everywhere in a bash script.

Source: [What is a simple explanation for how pipes work in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834086/what-is-a-simple-explanation-for-how-pipes-work-in-bash)

So, I'm pretty sure that `ls -lh -R |sort >> output.txt` it's working like a charm. Also, I tested on my system in `/` directoryand and it has functioned properly with 1.597.396 files and directories (of course I had to wait a little).

---

If you wish an alphabetically order after *file names* only, don't use `ls` with `-l` argument. If you don't wish to see all blank lines, use sort with `-u` argument. So, overall, you should use:

```
ls -h -R |sort -u >> output.txt
```

See `man ls` and `man sort` for more options or for for a better understanding.

Comment: it didn't worked for me....i want to show some OUTPUT
[link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6100171/).
And initially there were 2300 blank lines ....!!

Comment: @user182904 Of course you have a lot of blank lines (at least how many subdirectories are - check the output of `ls -lh -R ` only). And from what I see from your [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6100171/) all the lines are alphabetically ordered: alphabetically, `-r-- 1 linux ...` is before `-rw-rw-r-- 1 linux ...`, `-rw-rw-r-- 1 linux linux 124 Sep  5 23:27 count.js` before `-rw-rw-r-- 1 linux linux 125K Jun 16 03:28 Translation-ja.gz` and so on. So, nothing wrong.

Comment: @user182904 I edited my answer.

Comment: thnks for the answer, still i didn't get the answer, I wanted ....Thanks for telling about PIPING.:)
I think `find` is good alternative for my problem.....

Answer (score 1):

Try using `find` instead of `ls -R`, e.g. to find all the files > 100MB in the current directory and its subdirectories and then sort them by (human readable) size and list the largest 10

```
find . -size +100M -exec du -hd 1 {} \; | sort -hr | head -10
```

or (slightly more robust)

```
 while read -rd $'\0' file; do du -h "$file"; done < <(find . -size +100M -print0) | sort -hr | head -10
```

Comment: thnx for answer.....:)
it helped a lot ....